# Problem with dynamically updating a React Component within a chat project

Tags: reactjs

In my chat application, I am having trouble displaying user messages after send button is pressed.

I receive all the message data from an API and store it inside a state. Here is the relevant part.

I simplified the code because I think the problem is in the logic of my code and there are no syntax errors.

```
const Chat = (props) => {
  const [selectedRoom, setSelectedRoom] = useState({})
  const [roomMessages, setRoomMessages] = useState([])
  let roomMessagesData = []
  
  function getUserRoomMessages() {
     fetch("url").then((response) => {
        return response.json();
     }).then((requestData) => {
        setRoomMessages(requestData.message_list)
     });
  };
  
  function sendMessage(message) {
     fetch("url").then((response) => {
        return response.json();
     }).then((requestData) => {
        getUserRoomMessages()
     });
  } 

  function handleSendMessageButton() {
     let currentMsg = document.querySelector("#textBox").value;
     if (currentMsg != "") {
        sendMessage(currentMsg)
        roomMessagesData.push(
          <div className="message receiver">{currentMsg}</div>
        )
     }
     document.querySelector("#textBox").value = "";
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     getUserRoomMessages()
  }, [selectedRoom])

  // Note that: 
  // typeof roomMessages !== 'undefined' will always be true,
  // since initially, roomMessages = [], it is defined.
  // Instead just check if roomMessages is not empty, to avoid this operation.
  
  if (roomMessages.length > 0) {
  
     const sortedMessages = roomMessages.sort(
        (a,b)=> a.message_id > b.message_id ? 1 : -1
     );
     for (let i = 0; i<sortedMessages.length; i++) {
        if (sortedMessages[i].creator_id == user_id) {
           roomMessagesData.push(
              <div className="message receiver">
                {sortedMessages[i].message_text}
              </div>
           );
        } else {
           roomMessagesData.push(
              <div className="message sender"> 
                {sortedMessages[i].message_text}
              </div>
           );
        }
     };
  }
  
  return (
     <div>
       //some code
       <div className="chatBox">{roomMessagesData}</div>
       <div><input type="text" id="textBox"/></div>
       <div>
         <input
            id="btn"
            type="button"
            value="Send message" 
            onClick={handleSendMessageButton}
         />
       </div>
     </div>
  )
}
```

In this current logic, when I press send message button, the message is sent to the API successfully, but not displayed. Only after I refresh the page new message appear.

All of the calls to API are successful.
My idea is that when a user sends a new message I retrieve a newly updated list of messages from API which then should be re-rendered by `reactjs`. Or I want push a new element to `roomMessagesData` so that after it changes `reactjs` should reload its elements.

**The question is what is the problem in my code and what is it that I have do to achieve what I described above.**

Comment: `typeof roomMessages !== 'undefined'` you do not need to do that. a simple `if (roomMessages)` is enough. in JS if returns a `true`, in a if statement, if the parameter value is NOT  `null`, `undefined`, `0` (for numbers), `false` (obv).

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understood your code and if that is why messages are not getting displayed, but only useState variables are rerendering component, normal ones no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick review of the steps:

- So `handleSendMessageButton` triggers the `sendMessage` function which does a `POST`.
- And then `sendMessage` triggers a `GET` message using `getUserRoomMessages`.
- Within `getUserRoomMessages`, you trigger state update using `setRoomMessages`.
- And the rendered child `{roomMessagesData}` is dependant on the changes within `roomMessages` state.

Based on the above, the issue to be fixed is here:

```js
// ONLY re-renders if selectedRoom changes
useEffect(() => { getUserRoomMessages() }, [selectedRoom]);
```

Change the above to:

```js
// re-render if roomMessages changes,
// and the message should display automatically
useEffect(() => { getUserRoomMessages() }, [roomMessages]);
```

Remember, that `useEffect()` will only run again if certain "dependant" states change.

**UPDATE**

Despite suggesting the above, notice that it will create `infinite loop` because - `getUserRoomMessages` makes a API call and then updates `roomMessages` state which the `useEffect` depends on to re-render the component - thus leading to neverending re-rendering and numerous API calls.

Suggestion:

Since `getUserRoomMessages` is already called when the `onClick` is triggered, thus updating date... you can instead utilize the useEffect to run only when state is updated e.g.

```
let loaded = React.useRef(false); 

// Cleanup useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  // set to true on mount...
  isLoaded.current = true;
  // ... and to false on unmount
  return () => { isLoaded.current = false; };
}, [isLoaded, roomMessages]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have defined your list using a variable `let roomMessagesData = []`,whereas you need to use a state to define it. later on when you change that state , your component will be updated since a state has changed.
another way to go is by deploying a useEffect hook in which you will pass `roomMessagesData` as the second dependancy. This way , when that array changes, your component will rerender.

```
useEffect(() => {
       const copyRoomMessagesData = [...roomMessagesData]
  }, [roomMessagesData])
```

```
<div className="chatBox"> 
         {copyRoomMessagesData}
       </div>
```

Comment: Since he has already defined `roomMessages` as a STATE and `roomMessagesData` is dependant on that state... therefore instead of changing `roomMessagesData` to state... he should just add `roomMessages` as a "dependant" variable within the `useEffect`. Don't you think so?

Comment: That wouldn't work neither since, you will get into the useEffect hook with every change, but that doesn't change the fact that your ```roomMessagesData``` won't be rerendered.

Comment: Remember that if `roomMessages` changes, then `roomMessagesData` changes... do you agree? And if yes, then if `roomMessages` changes the the `useEffect` will run thus re-rendering the component.. agree? And the only time that `roomMessages` changes is after a `handleSendMessageButton` is triggered from within the `Input`... He is using `onClick` not `onChange`... by the way!! Actually, he should move that `onClick` from the `Input` to a `button`.

Comment: @MwamiTovi Well he should change a lot of things in his code but let's stick with the actual aim here. firstly, I examined what U suggested, but doesn't that cause an infinite loop? In what you suggested we are basically setting the state inside a useEffect hook which is observingit ( not setting it right inside it but by calling a function which does it ). secondly, I don't agree with what U said about re-rendering the component. I may be a bit off here but, I think only that part of our component will be re-rendered which we call upon it inside the useEffect hook.

Comment: I see your point actually, because `getUserRoomMessages` updates the `roomMessages` state, and it's called within the `useEffect`... yes I foresee an infinite loop. That's bridge we can cross, if he needs us to go there... he should remove that `getUserRoomMessages` call because apart from creating an infinite loop, it also run infinite API calls! But the aim, which he describes, for the component to re-render is only possible by adding the right "dependant" state/variables to the `useEffect`.